# JavaScript architecture - mediators, when to use them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, mediator

This is more of a general question about the structure of my JavaScript code and if I'm going in the right direction towards well structured code.

The current code I've got:

```
(function (myNamespace, $, undefined) {
    myNamespace.className = {
       init:function { } // do stuff
    }
} (window.myNamespace= window.myNamespace|| {}, jQuery)));

(function (myNamespace, $, undefined) {
        myNamespace.className2 = {
           init:function { } // do stuff
        }
} (window.myNamespace= window.myNamespace|| {}, jQuery)));
```

Obviously with the above code, I can use the same Namespace (as per page/site section) and call them via `myNamespace.className.init()` etc. I can also combine these if I want to, but I'm encapsulating classes for readability.

Now, I've been reading http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/ about the concept of mediators. My secondary question is when (and if) I should be using these? From className2 obviously I can do:

```
 myNamespace.className2 = {
               init:function { myNamespace.className.init() } // do stuff
            }
```

So why would this ever subscribe to className like `mediator.subscribe("classNameInit")` and publish that event in className?

I'm highly open to suggestions about the structure of my code as this is something I need to get right whilst I'm changing the way I write my JavaScript.

Comment: _With the mediator pattern, communication between objects is encapsulated with a mediator object. Objects no longer communicate directly with each other, but instead communicate through the mediator. This reduces the dependencies between communicating objects, thereby lowering the coupling._ (c) [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

Comment: I've tried to get my head around that and don't see reason why I'd be better off doing that rather than what I'm doing now? I've seen no real-world examples that prove it to be a useful thing.

Comment: once you will have a lot of modules that want to communicate with each other - you'll see how badly hard coupling scales.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find some valid points here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript

Comment: That's an excellent read. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use it when you have multiple pieces which will work together in unlimited combinations where you don't know all combinations ahead of time or where it's more efficient to assume all combinations.

Let's say you were building a social media app and you wrote a class to encapsulate a list of users.  On some screens, clicking on a user in the list opens their profile, on another screen perhaps clicking a user searches for every comment they left, and on a third screen something else happens.

If you were to write this *not* using mediator/pubsub, what you'd end up with is a bunch of if statements in the onclick event...

```
UserList.prototype.onUserClick = function(user) {
     // Check if we're supposed to open a popup
     if (this.mode === 'profile')

     // Check for something else
     else if (this.mode === 'something else')

     // Check for another case
     else if (this.mode === 'foo')
}
```

Mediator is a solution to this problem because it doesn't require that UserList have knowledge of every single situation it might end up in.  Instead, the above code in UserList could simply be refined to broadcast when a user is clicked on...

```
UserList.prototype.onUserClick = function(user) {
    this.publish('user-click', user);
}
```

Then each of your other screens or UI pieces can simply listen for the user-click message...

```
// On pages where there needs to be a popup profile
Mediator.onMessage('user-click', function(data) {
    showProfilePopup(data);
});

// Or perhaps on a search page
SearchBox.onMessage('user-click', function(data) {
    this.searchByUser(data);
});
```

Furthermore, where mediator begins to shine is because these other UI components, like `SearchBox` are not interested in specifically when `UserList` fires a user-click, they're interested only when a user-click is published, *other* UI controls on the page can fire user-click as well and these pieces can react to it.

On a side note, `className = { }` isn't creating a class.  What you probably want is `className = function() { }`.

Comment: I struggled with the methodology and reasoning behind this all for quite some time, but I've come to see that you're completely right (I've been writing a lot of mediated stuff today). Simply by creating UI GridViews in a mediator function, I can swap out UI libraries as and when I want. Marking this answer as correct as hopefully it'll help others on the subject. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer.  @thedixoon , I am looking into Jack Lawson's [link](http://thejacklawson.com/2011/06/mediators-for-modularized-asynchronous-programming-in-javascript/)Mediator.js as a template for creating a mediator "class" in js.  Have you seen it before?  Have you found anything more useful in your mediator module code efforts that you can share?  (+1 for the post)